# Sinatra response.status in "after" filters

Tags: ruby, sinatra

For some reason, in a Sinatra "after" filter I can't seem to access the current status code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

after do
  puts "After hook with code: #{response.status}"
end

get '/hi' do
  halt(401, "wtf?")
end
```

When running curl 127.0.0.1:4567/hi, it results in:

```
After hook for code: 200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically a function of how the methods are implemented in Sinatra. The methods we need to pay attention to are `call!`, `invoke` and `dispatch!`, all methods in [Sinatra::Base](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb) (as of v1.3.2).

`call!` is the top level method, and in there, it calls the following line of code:

```
invoke { dispatch! }
```

Now, `invoke` looks like this:

```
def invoke
  res = catch(:halt) { yield }
  res = [res] if Fixnum === res or String === res
  if Array === res and Fixnum === res.first
    status(res.shift)
    body(res.pop)
    headers(*res)
  elsif res.respond_to? :each
    body res
  end
end
```

It actually sets the response code on the basis of the thing you `throw` with `:halt`.  And `dispatch!` looks like:

```
def dispatch!
  static! if settings.static? && (request.get? || request.head?)
  filter! :before
  route!
rescue ::Exception => boom
  handle_exception!(boom)
ensure
  filter! :after unless env['sinatra.static_file']
end
```

See that `ensure` block?  That gets run as the `:halt` symbol that has been `thrown` sails up the stack trace.  Crucially, this is *before* the status setting code is run.

Comment: So there is no way to actually grab the correct status code in an after filter once halt is involved :( ?

Comment: No, since it's set after the `after` filters.

Comment: you could save it in a session var and access it from the after filter.

Comment: Ah, that's good.  I updated the link to point to the 1.3.2 code, so that it doesn't confuse people who find the answer and check out the code.